# How to make a window Draggable(C# Winforms)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, draggable

I have form. I have enabled the transparency on the form and I have removed it's Title Bar and Border. Inside that i have created a Custom UI, Which have the same features like a window. Basically, my idea is to create custom window.

Everything is working as expected but only the windows dragging is not working. I am not sure how to enable it. I googled for this. But i didn't find any useful info for me.

Please help me to implement this window dragging.

Comment: wat about `mouse` events.... ?? Try to use `mouse` events to move the window.

Comment: Default winform behavior is to drag a window by it's title bar, which you removed. Note that when users see a bar-less window they are less likely to drag&move it. If you still want this, you have to implement it yourself, for instance using the solution provided in Cyril's answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move a window on keypress + mouse (like linux ALT + mouse down)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100711/move-a-window-on-keypress-mouse-like-linux-alt-mouse-down)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms - Click/drag anywhere in the form to move it as if clicked in the form caption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184/winforms-click-drag-anywhere-in-the-form-to-move-it-as-if-clicked-in-the-form)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've implemented this behavior by capturing mousedown (uncapture on mouseup), and then mousemove.

Just move the form co-ordinates (left, top), equivalent amounts to the mouse movement (those events have the amount the mouse moved).

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourForm : Form
{
     private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
     private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
     private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;

     ///
     /// Handling the window messages 
     ///
     protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
     {
          base.WndProc(ref message);

          if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && (int)message.Result == HTCLIENT)
               message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to process `WM_NCHITTEST` message and return `HTCAPTION` for the portions of your custom window which work like the title bar does in a normal window. Windows will do the rest.