# Making the app unclickable (like it's there but not there)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form application and I want it not to be interacted with, so when we click on it, we have to click on whatever is below as if the application does not exist at all.

[image]

It is a bit difficult to explain, I will try to explain by giving an example. When we accidentally click on the auxiliary applications in the LOL game, this click means clicking on the game, and this is exactly what I want to do.

I tried drawing graphically but there is a lot of flickering as the drawing disappears and quickly comes back when the mouse passes.

Do you know a way I can go?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069717/letting-the-mouse-pass-through-windows-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3102238/17034

Comment: @DanielA.White: Your link is certainly useful but it is about Win32 API. The OP probably wants a C# and WinForms solution.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin I agree but Winforms is built on the Winapi

Comment: If you build a [per-pixel-alpha Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531201/7444103) and add `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to the styles in the CreateParams override, you get an untouchable Form. You can also apply opacity (make it semi-transparent) -- No child Controls allowed